# Ios: Saving / update more than one records at the same time with core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a similar question with [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497929/save-all-check-marked-rows-with-coredata).  Basically, is there a way to save / update multiple records from the table view at once with core data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is record which rows are checked and then alter the corresponding managed object appropriately.

A check mark is an accessory view so you would put the code to record which rows are checked (or save right then) in `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`

If you are using NSFetchedResults controller, you can just save the index path object in an array and it will record which managed object in the controllers `fetchedObjects` that you need to save/update because its table row got checked.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Since this is my first project that will be using core data, I was not clear on how all the mechanism of the updating (records) works.  I got it figured out just in the last hour...